# javascript doesn't produce new class name on html object

Tags: javascript, html

I use this javascript to produce "toggle" an extra word on class name by expanding `DropDown` function functionality and drop it when clicked:

```js
function DropDown(el) {
    this.dd = el;
    this.initEvents();
}
DropDown.prototype = {
    initEvents: function () {
        var obj = this;
        obj.dd.on('click', function (event) {

            $(this).toggleClass('active');
            /* event.stopPropagation();*/
            return false;
        });
    }
}

$(function () {

    var dd = new DropDown($('#dd'));

    $(document).click(function () {
        // all dropdowns
        $('.wrapper-dropdown').removeClass('active');
    });

});
```

HTML in which I want JavaScript to make effect looks like,
(I'm targeting class="wrapper-dropdown") :

```html
 <div class="wrapper">
     <div id='dd' class="wrapper-dropdown">1'st subject
         <ul class="dropdown">
             <li><a href="content.php?page=1">1</a></li>
             <li><a href="content.php?page=7">2</a></li>
             <li><a href="content.php?page=8">3</a></li>
         </ul>
     </div>
     <div id='dd' class="wrapper-dropdown">2'nd subject
         <ul class="dropdown">
             <li><a href="content.php?page=2">1</a></li>
             <li><a href="content.php?page=3">2</a></li>
         </ul>
     </div>
     <div id='dd' class="wrapper-dropdown">3'rd subject
         <ul class="dropdown"></ul>
     </div>
     <div id='dd' class="wrapper-dropdown">4'th subject
         <ul class="dropdown">
             <li><a href="content.php?page=9">1</a></li>
             <li><a href="content.php?page=11">2</a></li>
         </ul>
     </div> 
</div>
```

The problem is that JavaScript makes effect only on the first item in wrapper div

Answer (score 1):

Because you have multiple divs with `id='dd'` - ID's need to be unique.

Just add a `dd` class to your div like so:

```
 <div class="wrapper-dropdown dd">1'st subject
     <ul class="dropdown">
         <li><a href="content.php?page=1">1</a></li>
         <li><a href="content.php?page=7">2</a></li>
         <li><a href="content.php?page=8">3</a></li>
     </ul>
 </div>
```

And change the `el`: `var dd = new DropDown($('.dd'));`